# How to check if a JToken property value exists?

Tags: c#

I have a JObject; `myJObject`.

I want to instantiate a variable to `myJObject["property"]` and parse it to string if it exists.

If I do :

```
var myVar = myJObject["property"].ToString();
```

And "property" doesn't exist, this throws an error.

Is there a way to something like so :

```
var myVar = myJObject["property"] ?? myJObject["property"].ToString() || null;
```

I'm wondering if there's a neater way instead of having if else statements

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Simply use the [null-conditional](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/null-conditional-operators) operator:

```
string myVar = myJObject["property"]?.ToString();
```